# Error using MediaPlayer in my Android app (Cannot refer a non-final variable mp inside an inner class defined in a different method)

Tags: android, eclipse, media-player, inner-classes

I want to add a play button in my app (I'm using MediaPlayer) but maybe I'm doing something wrong when I declare my MediaPlayer.

```
package com.example.tones;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TonosSet extends Activity
{
    /**
     * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.tonos_set);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");

        MediaPlayer mp;

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view2);
        TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.namesong);
        TextView textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.artist);
        ImageButton play = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ButtonPlay);
        ImageButton stop = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ButtonStop);
        ImageButton setringtone = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ButtonRingtone);

        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:        
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.picture);
                textView1.setText("soundd");
                textView2.setText("aut");
                break;

            case 1:        
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.picture);
                textView1.setText("sound");
                textView2.setText("aut");
                 break;
        }

        play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(TonosSet.this, R.raw.sound1); //Error 
                mp.start();  //Error again
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My error is:

```
Cannot refer to a non-final variable mp inside an inner class defined in a different method
```

If I change `MediaPlayer mp;` to `final MediaPlayer mp;`, eclipse shows this error:

```
The final local variable cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type.
```

I don't know what's wrong with my app. I've followed a lot of tutorials but no one has the same error as me, even though I think I’m doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed my problem:

```
public class TonosSet extends Activity{

private MediaPlayer mp;
```

=D Thanks and sorry for this noob question.